# Where does cookies get stored by office word add-in on mac

Tags: javascript, macos, ms-word, office-js

i have stored the data in cookies by office task pane word add-in. to store the data in cookies i have used the following function.

```
   function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) 
        {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
        }
```

This function stores the data. But when i'm trying to clear the cookies it doen't get cleared. I have cleared the history and delete the cookies of safari browser, i have cleared the cache and cookies at location ~/Library/caches and ~/Library/cookies but still cookies are not cleared. If anyone know the exact location where the cookies get stored, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with Excel add-in.

Unlike JavaScript add-in on Windows, on Mac every time user closes the task pane, the embedded browser clears everything, including localStorage and Cookies.

A work around we came up with is to persist data to cells in a hidden sheet, but it should never be used for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where cookies are stored, but you can clear the cookies using this code:

```js
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    var cookieName = cookies[i].split("=")[0];
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=;";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to clear Internet explorer cookies as it use this browser internally.

Answer (score -1):

Clear the Internet history and cookies for INTERNET EXPLORER. This should solve the issue.